# Combine n Lists into 2 column tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have n lists of random length:

```
List_A = c("Alpha", "Beta")
List_B = c("Pi","Nu","Beta","Iota")
List_C = c("Tau")
```

I want to combine them into a 2 column tibble, where the first column is the name of the list where it came from, and the second is the value in the list:

Desired Output:

```
Treatment Value
List_A  Alpha           
List_A  Beta            
List_B  Pi          
List_B  Nu          
List_B  Beta            
List_B  Iota            
List_C  Tau
```

The best way I have found to do it is not elegant:

```
tibble(Treatment = "List_A", Value = List_A) %>%
bind_rows(tibble(Treatment = "List_B", Value = List_B)) %>%
bind_rows(tibble(Treatment = "List_C", Value = List_C))
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How about `stack(tibble::lst(List_A, List_B, List_C))`

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Base R way using `mget` and `stack` -

```
stack(mget(paste0('List_', c('A', 'B', 'C'))))
#Maybe simpler ? 
#stack(mget(paste0('List_', LETTERS[1:3])))

#  values    ind
#1  Alpha List_A
#2   Beta List_A
#3     Pi List_B
#4     Nu List_B
#5   Beta List_B
#6   Iota List_B
#7    Tau List_C
```